# Mongodb C# - How to group by fields ( Aggregate ) and get the count

Tags: c#, mongodb, group-by

'Table content'

`{ Age: 20, Gender: "Male", SomeField: "ABC" SomeParameter: 17.7 } { Age: 21, Gender: "Male", SomeField: "ABC" SomeParameter: 18.7 } { Age: 21, Gender: "Male", SomeField: "ABC" SomeParameter: 19.7 }`

'Can you please help me to get the C# code for the below using BsonDocument'

`SELECT Age,  count(SomeParameter) FROM Table1 WHERE SomeField = 'ABC' GROUP BY Age`

`I am looking for Output as below'

`Age, Count  {20, 1}, {21, 2}`

`Can you correct the mistake in the below code'

```
`IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = GetYourCollectionHere();

// there are many ways to create a filter. Using Builders here.
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("SomeField", "ABC"); 

var groupby = new BsonDocument("_id", new BsonDocument {
                        { "Age", "$Age" }
                    
                })
             
                .Add("count", new BsonDocument("$count", "$SomeParameter"));

var result = collection
                .Aggregate()
                .Match(filter)
                .Group(groupby);

// to see the output
foreach (var doc in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToJson());
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fnT7xOk0VXU) so you can try this c# code:

```cs
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("SomeField", "ABC"); 

var groupby = new BsonDocument {
    { "_id", "$Age" },
    { "Count", new BsonDocument { { "$sum", 1 } } }
};

var project = new BsonDocument {
    { "_id", 0 },
    { "Age", "$_id" },
    { "Count", 1 }
};

var result = collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .Group(groupby)
    .Project(project);
```